# How object detect using yolov4 and opencv dnn on ROS?

Tags: c++, opencv, ros, yolov4

I want to detect an object using the OpenCV DNN module by YOLOv4 on the ROS platform but It does not work. However, I runned opencv dnn module by yolov4 without the ROS platform. Same snippet of code does not work on the ROS platform.

**CMakeList.txt:** (I linked OpenCV)

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.2)
project(test_opencv)
  
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED 17)
add_compile_options(--std=c++17 -g3)
set(OpenCV_DIR "/home/usernamepc/opencv_build/opencv/build")

find_package(OpenCV 4.4.0 REQUIRED)
```

My code is here. This code works without ROS but doesn't work with ROS.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv){

ros::init(argc, argv, "test_opencv");

int inpWidth = 608;
int inpHeight = 608;
int count = 0;
std::cout << "OpenCV version : " << CV_VERSION << std::endl;
std::cout << "Major version : " << CV_MAJOR_VERSION << std::endl;
std::cout << "Minor version : " << CV_MINOR_VERSION << std::endl;
std::cout << "Subminor version : " << CV_SUBMINOR_VERSION << std::endl;

vector<string> class_names;
{
    ifstream class_file("/home/USERNAMEPC/people_detection_ws/src/test_opencv/input/data/obj_license.names");

    if (!class_file)
    {
        cerr << "failed to open classes.txt\n";
        return 0;
    }

    string line;
    while (getline(class_file, line))
    {
        class_names.push_back(line);
        cout << "Data: " << line << endl;
    }
}
string video = "/home/USERNAMEPC/people_detection_ws/src/test_opencv/input/plate/1.mp4";
VideoCapture cap(video); 
auto net = readNetFromDarknet("/home/USERNAMEPC/people_detection_ws/src/test_opencv/input/cfg/yolov4_obj_license.cfg",
                              "/home/USERNAMEPC/people_detection_ws/src/test_opencv/input/custom_license.weights");

auto output_names = net.getUnconnectedOutLayersNames();
double inference_fps = 0;
double total_fps = 0;

Mat frame, blob;
vector<Mat> detections;
while (waitKey(1) < 1)
{

    cap >> frame;

    if (frame.empty())
    {
        waitKey();
        break;
    }
    auto total_start = chrono::steady_clock::now();

    imshow("frame", frame);
    waitKey(1);
    cv::dnn::blobFromImage(frame, blob, 0.00392, Size(inpWidth, inpHeight), Scalar(), true, false, CV_32F);

    net.setInput(blob);
    if (blob.empty())
    {
        std::cout << "blob is empty" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    auto dnn_start = chrono::steady_clock::now();
    cout << "6 " << endl;

    net.forward(detections, output_names);

    cout << "7  " << endl;

    auto dnn_end = chrono::steady_clock::now();

    vector<int> indices[NUM_CLASSES];
    vector<Rect> boxes[NUM_CLASSES];
    vector<float> scores[NUM_CLASSES];

    for (auto &output : detections)
    {
        const auto num_boxes = output.rows;
        for (int i = 0; i < num_boxes; i++)
        {

            auto x = output.at<float>(i, 0) * frame.cols;
            auto y = output.at<float>(i, 1) * frame.rows;
            auto width = output.at<float>(i, 2) * frame.cols;
            auto height = output.at<float>(i, 3) * frame.rows;
            Rect rect(x - width / 2, y - height / 2, width, height);

            for (int c = 0; c < NUM_CLASSES; c++)
            {
                auto confidence = *output.ptr<float>(i, 5 + c);
                if (confidence >= CONFIDENCE_THRESHOLD)
                {
                    boxes[c].push_back(rect);
                    scores[c].push_back(confidence);
                    detected_control = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    for (int c = 0; c < NUM_CLASSES; c++)
    {
        NMSBoxes(boxes[c], scores[c], 0.0, NMS_THRESHOLD, indices[c]);
    }

    for (int c = 0; c < NUM_CLASSES; c++)
    {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < indices[c].size(); ++i)
        {

            const auto color = colors[c % NUM_COLORS];
            auto idx = indices[c][i];
            auto &rect = boxes[c][idx];
            rectangle(frame, Point(rect.x, rect.y), Point(rect.x + rect.width, rect.y + rect.height), color, 3);
            ostringstream label_ss;
            label_ss << class_names[c] << ": " << fixed << setprecision(2) << scores[c][idx];
            auto label = label_ss.str();

            int baseline;
            auto label_bg_sz = getTextSize(label.c_str(), FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL, 1, 1, &baseline);
            rectangle(frame, Point(rect.x, rect.y - label_bg_sz.height - baseline - 10), Point(rect.x + label_bg_sz.width, rect.y), color, FILLED);
            putText(frame, label.c_str(), Point(rect.x, rect.y - baseline - 5), FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL, 1, Scalar(0, 0, 0));
        }
    }

    auto total_end = chrono::steady_clock::now();
    inference_fps = 1000.0 / chrono::duration_cast<chrono::milliseconds>(dnn_end - dnn_start).count();
    total_fps = 1000.0 / chrono::duration_cast<chrono::milliseconds>(total_end - total_start).count();
    ostringstream stats_ss;
    stats_ss << fixed << setprecision(2);
    stats_ss << "Inference FPS: " << inference_fps << ", Total FPS: " << total_fps;
    auto stats = stats_ss.str();

    int baseline;
    auto stats_bg_sz = getTextSize(stats.c_str(), FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL, 1, 1, &baseline);
    rectangle(frame, Point(0, 0), Point(stats_bg_sz.width, stats_bg_sz.height + 10), Scalar(0, 0, 0), FILLED);
    putText(frame, stats.c_str(), Point(0, stats_bg_sz.height + 5), FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL, 1, Scalar(255, 255, 255));
    // namedWindow("output");
    count++;
}

cout << "Inference FPS: " << inference_fps << ", Total FPS: " << total_fps << endl;

ros::spin();

return 0; }
```

I get an error when the code goes to step

> net.forward(detections, output_names);

Error is below:

> OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (dims <= 2) in reshape, file
> /build/opencv-L2vuMj/opencv-3.2.0+dfsg/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp,
> line 1032 terminate called after throwing an instance of
> 'cv::Exception'   what():
> /build/opencv-L2vuMj/opencv-3.2.0+dfsg/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp:1032:
> error: (-215) dims <= 2 in function reshape

When I use GDB debugger, I get output of error like a below:

> (gdb) bt
> #0  0x00007ffff61b5e87 in __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:51
>
> #1  0x00007ffff61b77f1 in __GI_abort () at abort.c:79
>
> #2  0x00007ffff680c957 in  () at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
>
> #3  0x00007ffff6812ae6 in  () at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
>
> #4  0x00007ffff6812b21 in  () at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
>
> #5  0x00007ffff6812d54 in  () at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
>
> #6  0x00007ffff77c38a2 in cv::error(cv::Exception const&) () at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_core.so.3.2
>
> #7  0x00007ffff77c39bf in cv::error(int, cv::String const&, char const*, char const*, int) () at
> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_core.so.3.2
>
> #8  0x00007ffff7734b1c in cv::Mat::reshape(int, int) const () at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_core.so.3.2
>
> #9  0x00007ffff6efb344 in cv::dnn::ConvolutionLayerImpl::finalize(cv::_InputArray const&,
> cv::_OutputArray const&) () at
> /home/USERNAMEPC/opencv_build/opencv/build/lib/libopencv_dnn.so.4.4
>
> #10 0x00007ffff6eb12d7 in cv::dnn::dnn4_v20200609::Layer::finalize(std::vector<cv::Mat,
> std::allocator<cv::Mat> > const&, std::vector<cv::Mat,
> std::allocator<cv::Mat> >&) () at
> /home/USERNAMEPC/opencv_build/opencv/build/lib/libopencv_dnn.so.4.4
>
> #11 0x00007ffff6ed1ff3 in cv::dnn::dnn4_v20200609::Net::Impl::allocateLayer(int, std::map<int,
> cv::dnn::dnn4_v20200609::(anonymous namespace)::LayerShapes,
> std::less, std::allocator<std::pair<int const,
> cv::dnn::dnn4_v20200609::(anonymous namespace)::LayerShapes> > >
> const&) () at
> /home/USERNAMEPC/opencv_build/opencv/build/lib/libopencv_dnn.so.4.4
>
> #12 0x00007ffff6ed3ff2 in cv::dnn::dnn4_v20200609::Net::Impl::allocateLayers(std::vector<cv::dnn::dnn4_v20200609::LayerPin,
> std::allocator<cv::dnn::dnn4_v20200609::LayerPin> > const&) () at
> /home/USERNAMEPC/opencv_build/opencv/build/lib/libopencv_dnn.so.4.4
>
> #13 0x00007ffff6ed7675 in cv::dnn::dnn4_v20200609::Net::Impl::setUpNet(std::vector<cv::dnn::dnn4_v20200609::LayerPin,
> std::allocator<cv::dnn::dnn4_v20200609::LayerPin> > const&) () at
> /home/USERNAMEPC/opencv_build/opencv/build/lib/libopencv_dnn.so.4.4
>
> #14 0x00007ffff6ed8ac3 in cv::dnn::dnn4_v20200609::Net::forward(cv::_OutputArray const&,
> std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits,
> std::allocator >,
> std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char,
> std::char_traits, std::allocator > > > const&) () at
> /home/USERNAMEPC/opencv_build/opencv/build/lib/libopencv_dnn.so.4.4
>
> #15 0x0000555555561c0e in main(int, char**) (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffd918) at
> /home/USERNAMEPC/people_detection_ws/src/test_opencv/src/test_opencv.cpp:147

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I deleted `cv_bridge` and installed from source code on github. End of the day, code is running.